# Mechanical ribcage having variable number of ribs and derived heights

Tags: modeling, modifiers, transforms, bezier-curves, constraints

How do you create ribs that shrink in height along the inside of a track?

Here is a screen shot showing the problem:

[image: Ribcage]

With the array and mirror settings hidden, you can see a quarter rib:

[image: Hidden Ribs]

The ribs do not decrease in height, which causes them to extend beyond the track:

[image: Ribcage Offset]

I'd like to limit the height of each rib such that it connects to the support beam, shown selected here:

[image: Support Beam]

How can this be accomplished without modeling each rib individually (i.e., using curves, empties, constraints, arrays, and so on)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Method 1: even rib size

You can use a combination of some modifiers such as:

- **Array** (using object offset pointing to an empty to get the step
  distance to increase; notice that the empty doesn't have the same Y coordinate of the object origin, so each step the repeated object gets nearer to the center)
- **Boolean** (to cut away the parts that exceed the middle line with a "control" box)
- **Mirror** (to repeat the other half)

[image]

### Method 2: slightly deformed ribs

Use a regular **X-axis Array** modifier (much simpler to set up than the array previusly presented) and deform the result with a **lattice** with two control points only in order for each direction (U,V,W) to get a linear deformation:

[image]

While the second method is probably faster, the first would give you more control and precision.

[image]